# Is it possible to display a browser window inside a Tmux Pane?

Tags: tmux

I'm using Tmux / Vim on Mac OSX and I like to split the windows for testing and development. I would like to know if its possible to dock safari or another browser inside a tmux window so I would have code on the left side and the browser on the right.

Cheers!

Comment: You want a [tiling window manager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076507/osx-tiling-window-managers) for that...

Comment: I think you are right @jasonwryan

Comment: @jasonwryan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076507/osx-tiling-window-managers link you shared is dead

Answer (score 2):

If you can make the browser show in your terminal, then the answer to your question is YES. otherwise: **NO**.

From tmux homepage:

```
tmux is a terminal multiplexer    

What is a terminal multiplexer? It lets you switch easily between several 
programs in one terminal, detach them (they keep running in the background) and 
reattach them to a different terminal.
```

Notable web browsers you could actually use in the terminal are [elinks](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/elinks/), [w3m](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/w3m/) or for a complete graphical interface, [NetSurf](http://www.netsurf-browser.org/about/).